# Remove default optgroup label '0' in array select using Symfony2

Tags: symfony, select, label, default, optgroup

I have a form that shows a drop-down menu to select a single value from an array defined in params.yml.

The dropdown displays '0' as an optgroup label above the list of values to be selected.

How can I get rid of this default label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the default OptGroup with something like the "Standard Hours" and "Other Hours" as defined below.

```
$category_choices = array(
          'Standard Hours' => array(
            2 => '2',
            4 => '4',
            6 => '6',
            8 => '8'
          ),
          'Other Hours' => array(
            1 => '1',
            3 => '3',
            5 => '5',
            7 => '7',
            9 => '9',
            10 => '10'
          )
        );

        $builder
            ->add('hours', 'choice', array(
              'choices' => $category_choices
         ));
```

Alternatively, if you don't want OptGroup labels at all, and only selectable entries, you can just skip out on the nested arrays altogether.

```
$builder
    ->add('hours', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        1 => '1',
        2 => '2',
        3 => '3',
        4 => '4'
    )
));
```

In your case, you want something like:

```
$builder
    ->add('hours', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => arrayFromParamsYML
));
```

Comment: Thanks but in my case, I want no optgroup label at all, knowing that the array has to come from params.yml as I use its values in several different forms. Any idea ?

Comment: My second code snippet explains how to have no opt group.